# The add to cart button takes me to the product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code to add products from the store, but when you click to add products they are added correctly. The problem is that I do not want to go to the product page. I want him to stay in the store.

The code is this:

```
/**
 * Override loop template and show quantities next to add to cart buttons
 */
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',
           'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        $html = '<form action="' . esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) . '" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
        $html .= woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false );
        $html .= '<button type="submit" class="button alt">' . esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ) . '</button>';
        $html .= '</form>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Help!

Comment: Redirect happens somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You need to accomplish this using jQuery and AJAX.

- You need to `event.preventDefault()` the form.
- Submit you data using AJAX call using jQuery `$.post()` method
- Amend your cart list element using jQuery `.append()` method

Regarding how to get the URL which you need to submit your data, you can localize the URLs in variables and then extract them as following:

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    /**
     * frontend ajax requests.
     */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'frontend-ajax', JS_DIR_URI . 'frontend-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_localize_script( 'frontend-ajax', 'frontend_ajax_object',
        array( 
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'add_to_cart_url' => $add_to_cart_url,
            'add_to_cart_text' => $add_to_cart_text,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

P.S. You need to pass your cart URL and text to the `theme_enqueue_scripts` function.

Comment: I don't handle this much. Isn't there an easier way to put a code in function.php?